# Unexpected results when using the location bias parameter with google maps api places web-api when deploying, result is not within suggested radius

Tags: google-maps, web-services, google-places-api

I am trying to use the Google Maps API, specifically the places web-api in my web app so that a user can search by name and have a result shown to them on a map.

When I tested my app locally, that is what happened (even without the location bias parameter), and when done just by putting the encoded URL into a chrome window it returns the expected result. However, when I do this in my deployed web app I am getting a result in Eugene, OR in the USA (location bias coordinates are currently set for Ottawa, Canada). This is not in keeping with the location bias parameter. When I set up my elephantSQL database, and my Netlify frontend and Render backend, I followed instructions from my school to select USA WEST as the location. I am wondering if by doing this that the information being used by Google Maps API through the deployed web app is based on this set location and not by the user's information being passed to it?

I am using the following encoded URL to do this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?fields=formatted_address%2Cname%2Ctypes%2Cgeometry%2Cplace_id&input=equator%2Ccoffee&inputtype=textquery&locationbias=circle%3A1000%45.4215296%2C-75.69719309999999&key=API_KEY

I have set the location bias lat, lng coordinates from the user's location based on the city and country provided when they signed up. This would have hopefully provided them with local responses for their search.

I have added console.logs to my code to verify that the coordinates expected are being received by my function and passed to the function handling my google maps api call. I don't know of any other way to verify that it is doing what I expect. The results though, are not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From the URL you posted:
`&locationbias=circle%3A1000%45.4215296%2C-75.69719309999999`

Your locationbias is wrong, if I decode it, I get:
`locationbias=circle:1000E.4215296,-75.69719309999999`

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place#locationbias) that should be:
`circle:radius@lat,lng`

Which URL encoded would probably be: `circle%3A1000%4045.4215296%2C-75.69719309999999`